# The ultimate addition to anything

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> Kick a man when he's down.

Because of me, John dies at the end.

What am I?

---

I had the idea to this the last time I had some of those amazing/nasty cylinders for dinner.
Man, do I love food. Especially the 8 (no not that one). Get it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be

> soy sauce?

Kick a man when he's down.

> "Kick a man" => Kikkoman, a popular soy sauce brand

Because of me, John dies at the end.

> A mysterious serum called 'Soy Sauce' plays a major part in the film

I had the idea to this the last time I had some of those amazing/nasty cylinders for dinner.

> Egg rolls?

Especially the 8 (no not that one). Get it up!

> No clue what this is referring to

Comment: Correct! The brand name is the intended solution, with the 8 referring to character count. Getting something up removes the "on the ground" condition, thus leading closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Partial:
Kick a man when he's down

> It's a phrase which means to hurt someone who is already weak.

Because of me, John dies at the end

> John dies at the end is a movie released in 2012.
> This matches with the clue you will see when you edit the question.

What am I?

> This maybe suggests that the solution is a thing rather than a person.

And

> But I don't know how this things are relevant to each other or even they are relevant to finding solution because there is the trivia tag in the question.

Comment: You found the right John. The rest ist to vague to comment on yet.